# Loading Canvas & WooCommerce translation file in child theme

Tags: plugins, child-theme, localization

I'm trying to localise a site (Canvas child theme). I already have the translated .po and .mo files.

I uploaded the WooCommerce translation files to `child-theme/woocommerce/i18n/languages/` in the child theme and the Canvas translation file to `child-theme/lang/`. This follows the same directory structure as the parent theme and plugin.

I have also defined WPLANG as 'af_AF'

In my functions.php I have the following function

```
function weg_localisation() { 
load_theme_textdomain('woothemes', get_stylesheet_directory() . '/lang'); 
unload_textdomain('woocommerce'); 
load_textdomain('woocommerce', get_stylesheet_directory() . '/woocommerce/i18n/languages.woocommerce-af_AF.mo'); 
} 
add_action('init', 'weg_localisation');
```

Unfortunately I'm having no success with this. Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: Shouldn't `'/woocommerce/i18n/languages.woocommerce-af_AF.mo'` rather be (as you stated above) `'/woocommerce/i18n/languages/woocommerce-af_AF.mo'`? Note the slash after `languages`.

Comment: Haha, thanks that worked for the WooCommerce translations. Still having trouble getting the theme textdomain to load.

Comment: Okay, that's good. As for the theme, what is the exact file name of the MO file? It **should** be `af_AF.mo` (and nothing more/less).

Comment: Managed to get it working, see answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a syntax error in loading the WooCommerce translations and I managed to get the parent theme translations working by following the same method I used for the WooCommerce translations.

```
function weg_localisation() {
    unload_textdomain( 'woothemes' );
    load_textdomain('woothemes', get_stylesheet_directory() . '/lang/af_AF.mo');
    unload_textdomain('woocommerce');
    load_textdomain('woocommerce', get_stylesheet_directory() . '/woocommerce/i18n/languages/woocommerce-af_AF.mo');
}
add_action('init', 'weg_localisation');
```